# How can I add multiple GridBagLayout attributes in the 'Constraints' section of an element in Groovy (2.5.5)?

Tags: groovy

This is driving me mad at the moment, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated!! This is simple enough in Java, but when called from groovy I cannot get multiple gbc properties defined in a single constraint.

I have read on a couple of old posts on the net that GridBagConstraints properties such as gridx etc can be added as follows from [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Add-passwordField-to-UISupport-dialog/td-p/6252).

code snippet of interest:

```
label(text:'Username', constraints:gbc(gridx:0,gridy:0,gridwidth:2))
```

However this won't work for me and I didn't expect it to as the syntax appears to be from years ago so I assume an old API. (error message below when I try the above)

```
Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
```

I can't see how this could work as as surely the format needs to be:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints()
label("Username: ", constraints:gbc.gridx=0)
```

The two lines of code above run, but then I have the problem that I can't add more than one entry in the 'constraints:' section, and obviously I need to add 'gridy=0' etc.

Has anybody got any solution on how this should work?

Thanks

Taylor.

Comment: This implies you have not set up to use `GridBagLayout`.  It's hard to see, as there's not enough code in the question.  Do you have a small example that shows the issue?

Comment: the code from the [link](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Add-passwordField-to-UISupport-dialog/td-p/6252) you've provided works fine in groovy 2.5.5. I guess you just mixing `=` and `:` symbols when defining multiple values...